# Connecting to web service | unable to get request | Clear aaplication pool works fine

Tags: .net, iis-7.5, webservices-client

In my application I have to connect to web service and get the results. Currently it's a public property as I have so many calls to service. I'm aborting and closing the service only when the service goes to faulted state. My application is hosted in IIS 7.5. When I deploy my appication to IIS it's working fine for some time. When the application is idle for some time(for eg., a day), the next day my application related to service call module is not working.

It works only when I recycle the application pool. What would be the issue here? What is the best way to connect to the webservice if there are so many calls to webservice? Do I need to create new client every time or is there any other way?

If you need any more clarifications, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are there any timeouts in your client application? Does only the first call fail or every consecutive ones also?

We have a similar situation with a client&webservice - when the first user in a day calls this webservice he sometimes gets an error which is basically a timeout expired. What we found out was that the IIS pool releases resources after some idle time and when the service gets its first call the resources need to be put into memory etc. The main consumer for this is Crystal Reports in our case.

After the first call is made and resources set the application works as expected.

Comment: How did you fix your issue?

Comment: We changed compilation debug to false and made some general cleaning of the code. The first call still takes longer but the timeouts are gone (for now), or perhaps the first unlucky user got used to it (terrible I know :)) [this looks similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914702/how-to-increase-the-timeout-to-a-web-service-request)