# ASP.NET page webmethod AJAX call Request timed out

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I have webmethod on asp page

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string MyMethod(string requestObject)
    {
        // here is operation that takes approximately 200 - 300 second
    }
```

Also there is an AJAX method on page

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'MyPage.aspx/MyMethod',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: somedata,
        timeout: 300000,

        success: function (response) {
            some handler
        }
    });
```

When I try to call this ajax method I get 'System.Web.HttpException: Request timed out.'

I tried to add executionTimeout="300" to  element in web.config.
And issue is resolved. But as I understand this will increase timeouts for all application.
I don't want to do this.
Is there a more proper way to fix timeout exception?
And does executionTimeout parameter set timeout for all requests or just for async requests?

Comment: Try this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914702/how-to-increase-the-timeout-to-a-web-service-request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `Server.ScriptTimeout` ?

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string MyMethod(string requestObject)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Server.ScriptTimeout = 300;
    // here is operation that takes approximately 200 - 300 second
}
```

> And does executionTimeout parameter set timeout for all requests or
>   just for async requests?

This is for all requests which do no set their own timeout.
From the server point of view, there is no http difference between a sync or async request.

Comment: Hi! Sorry but I can't use 'Server' in my webmethod. Method is static so this property is not available.

Comment: @TarasLviv sorry did not notice the static. I edited my answer.