# Is It Possible to stop a server request manually while the request is being processed by the server

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-services, asp.net-ajax

I am using asp.net and Ajax functionalities to make requests to server via web services for a search functionality. On click of search button, I am making the screen inactive by displaying a loading image over it. The issue is some searches takes longer time, and the user is forced to wait till the results are fetched. Is there any way the search can be cancelled manually, like a button click while the search is being performed by the server.

Any help or alternates will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is to set timeout on your ajax call, take a look here:[asp-net-page-webmethod-ajax-call-request-timed-out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040695/asp-net-page-webmethod-ajax-call-request-timed-out)

Another thing is to use javascript setTimeOut to display the user a message after a few seconds saying "its taking too long. wait for results or Abort?" where the "Abort" is a link that refreshes the page.